# PHP Dropdown List variable

Tags: php, mysql, variables, post

I am trying to have a drop down menu where you can choose from 3 options. I've got the following code, but I can't seem to get my third option to work. Any ideas?

```
        $_POST['faction'] = ($_POST['faction'] == "s")? "S" : "K";
```

I want to add a third option which is "R" and I can't get it to work.

Ideas please?

Comment: What do you mean dropdown? PHP is executed server side. Why not just repeatedly use `if-else`?

Comment: Are you trying to get drop down value in PHP  ?

Answer (score 1):

Although adding another `ternary` statement to your statement is possible I think it will affect the code readability.

Using `array` will make this simpler.

```
$option_array = array('r' => 'R', 's' => 'S', 'k' => 'K');

if (array_key_exists($_POST['faction'])) { 
    $_POST['faction'] = $option_array[$_POST['faction']]
}
```

You could choose to add the `array_key_exists` to make sure you are not updating `$_POST['faction']` if `$_POST['faction']` contains other values, but this is your choice.

Another approach similar to yours with multiple ternary operations:

```
$_POST['faction'] = ($_POST['faction'] == "s") ? ($_POST['faction'] == "r" ? "R" : "S") : "K";
```

Comment: What it is that in my table, I've got the 3 options and from a drop down menu in a html code, it's selecting that option and then displaying it as information. I tried your code with the multiple ternary operations but that didn't work.

Comment: Please post output of `var_dump($_POST)`